# extract predictor names from (generalized) linear models in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

When predictors are factors (categories), `coef(glm)` or `summary(glm)` list all dummy variables. Is there a way to list just the variable names present in the model as a character vector without splitting up a single factor into C-1 dummy variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, just figured it out myself:

```
attr(glm$terms, "term.labels")
```

Comment: although this may not give what you want when using function in the formula e.. `~ I(var1^2) + factor(var2)`. Maybe something along the lines of `all.vars(formula(m))[-1]` would suit